# Write Macro or shortcut for running the whole script

Tags: r, macros, shortcut

ich have a question within my a R Script. My Script looks like this:

```
variable <- File1
number<- 1
#after that there are a view calculations
```

With the variable i select the File1, which is a datatable with my values for calculation.
With number i address the line of my "Results-datatable" in which line the results get printed. So i have 105 Files. It all works when i always change the variable to File1, File2,... File 105 and the number from 1 to 2,3,...105 by hand an select the whole code and run it.

So my question is, is there a much smarter solution instead of changing the variable and number by hand 105-times?

Thanks for any smart suggestions.

Comment: First step: Turn your script into a function that accepts `variable` and `number` as parameters and returns the desired result. Second step: Call it in a double loop that stores the results (e.g., two nested `lapply` loops).

Comment: Hi Roland, thank you for your comment. I have to say, that im new in R so i have to search how to implement your idea. I´ve never wrote a function before and i have not so much time... But thank you. I hoped there are some shortcuts in R that help me.

Comment: Sorry, but every R user must know how to write a function if they want to do more than what the average Excel user does. Fortunately, writing functions is extremely easy in R because it strives to be a functional language (which makes it necessary to be able to define functions).

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
foo <- function(variable, number) {
   #after that there are a view calculations
   return(list(result1, result2, ...)) #no list needed if only one result is desired
}

#loops
result <- lapply(vector_of_filenames, function(variable) 
            lapply(vector_of_numbers, foo, variable = variable)
          )
```